# How can I explain a race from Eberron showing up in Faerûn?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms, planes, eberron

I know Eberron and Faerûn are different planes, but I have players who want to play warforged. What connections exist between the planes to facilitate a Eberron race ending up in Faerûn?

I am looking for a way to explain how the level 0/1 got to Faerûn. He does not need to be the source of the effect.

It was my understanding that there are locations in lore that describe semi-permanent gateways between planes, and I am trying to find out if there is a chain I could use to get someone from Eberron to The Sword Coast.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83321/discussion-on-question-by-hehe3301-what-is-an-easy-in-game-mechanic-to-have-a-ra).

Comment: Point of clarification: is it important that this is actually an _Eberron_ warforged which has hopped between settings, or would you also be okay with lore featuring warforged in the Realms setting "natively"?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### Eberron and Faerûn might be connected, possibly

It is the default of D&D campaign settings that they are connected to one another through the “multiverse,” which refers to all the *other* planes beyond the Material one the campaign setting is set on. In AD&D 2e, those planes themselves became their own major campaign setting, Planescape. And it is possible for Eberron to be connected to Planescape’s “Great Wheel” of planes, but it certainly is awkward.

Originally, in 3rd edition, Eberron’s cosmology was unique. It had Astral, Ethereal, and Shadow planes, or approximations of them (i.e. spells relying on them still work), but they didn’t seem to connect to the wider Great Wheel or serve the same “connective” value. The planes it does have weren’t other dimensions, but literally moons you could see from the surface of Eberron. And they didn’t neatly line up with the planes of the Great Wheel. And the afterlife and gods were all different, too.

But then, nothing said Eberron *didn’t* connect to the wider multiverse, per se. Any such connection was left out, but not ruled out. You could definitely make it work—noted expert afroakuma does so in his Planescape Q&As, for example. For that matter, as [Quadratic Wizard points out](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/131927/4563), *Player’s Handbook* lists Eberron as being one of the campaign settings connected to the multiverse, though it doesn’t bother to explain *how*.<sup>1</sup> The moons seen in the sky could just be lenses into the outer planes, appearing as bubbles in the night sky, for instance. This takes some hand-waving since several of those planes aren’t really any one plane in the Great Wheel, but it *can* be made to work. We’ll assume connections exists, then.

1. <sub>And, for that matter, it also lists Mystara, which is even harder to make fit into the multiverse than Eberron is.</sub>

#### Those connections, if they exist, are rarely used, but we have Merrix

Even if those connections exist, they are rarely used; Toril doesn’t know about Eberron and Eberron certainly doesn’t know about Toril or the rest of the planes. If people did, they’d almost-certainly seek them out rather than the fairly-extreme approaches to avoiding Dolurrh that some in Eberron take—like joining the Blood of Vol or a cult to the Keeper. We’d hear about it, and by-and-large we do not.

But those connections could be rare and difficult to use. The “lensing” effect that produces Eberron’s moons can also make those sections of the planes difficult to leave for the wider Great Wheel. Outsiders native to them could have restrictions on their behavior that prevents them from explaining the situation or allowing Eberron’s peoples out—or the wider planes’ peoples in.

And then the limited ways out of Eberron would be known to extremely few. Some dragons, presumably. Maybe Erandis d’Vol herself. Tira Miron, at least if she’s everything she’s purported to be, probably would, and so would Oalian. The Aereni Undying Court, perhaps.

But if anyone knows it, then we can be damn sure that **Merrix d’Cannith** knows it. Because knowing all the secrets and darkest lore about the metaphysics of his world is pretty much Merrix d’Cannith’s *raison d’être*.

That leads us to an easy explanation: the only person known to still be creating (normal, functional, playable) warforged is Merrix d’Cannith, operating out of an illegal creation forge buried deep within Cannith South’s holdings in Sharn. He is known (to players and DMs, if not to any of the Eberron public) to continue producing warforged for the sake of various experiments. And if he knew about connections to Faerûn? *It would be weird if he **didn’t** send some through.*

As for how, Eberron’s always got **eldritch machines**, which are literally just “plot hook” in industrial form. I prefer that over an awkward trek through Eberron’s moon–lenses to get to the Great Wheel and then somehow get to Toril, because that’s a rather-unlikely journey for a 1st-level character. Merrix d’Cannith has already known to have performed several experiments on eldritch machines, so this is no great stretch.

### Faerûn could reasonably produce warforged too

Faerûn is just chock-full of preposterously-powerful mages, and things like golems are already things there. And given Faerûn’s propensity for mages who sit in towers doing research without ever interacting with the rest of the world, for one of those to have pursued the idea of imbuing an artificial construct with real life, succeed, and *then not tell anybody about it*, is entirely in keeping with the campaign setting as a whole. In comments, nitsua60 mentions that the new *Dragon Heist* adventure includes new constructs, and in [his answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/131929/4563), Matt Vincent mentions the techsmiths of Gond and their Gondsmen, which are much of the way to warforged already. So for there to be just one, or a handful, of warforged in Faerûn is quite plausible.

The key thing that separates Faerûn and Eberron here isn’t the prevalence of magic, but Eberron’s *industrialization* of magic, which Faerûn hasn’t done. As long as warforged aren’t disrupting Faerûnian societies through large populations demanding rights and recognition, and having disruptive economic effects, then the setting of Faerûn won’t be threatened by their existence.

---

#### A semi-aside: connecting Eberron to the Great Wheel

As described above, you can connect Eberron to the Great Wheel, but it is awkward. Below, I’ll describe some of what has to be dealt with in general for this, but since you’re *not* playing in Eberron there isn’t really any reason you need to pin any of these answers down. Faerûn doesn’t really care about how Eberron links up to its cosmology, just whether or not it does. For the purposes of a Faerûn character, it’s enough to just say “it does” and leave the details of how that works out and how you explain Eberron’s unique features unexplained (and possibly to be explored later, in play, since after all the characters themselves probably wouldn’t know).

#### Dealing with moons: Shavarath as an example

For example, Shavarath is basically the Blood War: celestials vs. demons vs. devils. In the Great Wheel, the Blood War plays out across the three planes between Hell and the Abyss, with the celestials coming from yet another set of planes, and numerous schemes and flanking maneuvers spreading out across all the planes. In Eberron, that all is confined to just Shavarath.

To make that work, you have to imagine that Shavarath is connected to some particular plane or portion of a plane in the Great Wheel—perhaps, the place where the fighting of the Blood War is thickest. And then there are portals, perhaps, in each of the encampments for the three sides, connecting further on to the Heavens, Hells, or Abyss, making those seem like part of Shavarath from an Eberron perspective.

#### Afterlife: what *is* Dolurrh?

The other major issue is the afterlife. If Eberron’s beliefs are true (and while there’s wiggle room to make them *not* true, the consistency of these beliefs across many cultures and religions makes that a bit of a stretch), souls mostly *don’t* go to some befitting afterlife, as they do in the rest of the multiverse (and there is *not* much wiggle room on that!). Instead, they go to Dolurrh, a gray blandness where they are broken down and recycled. The Church of the Silver Flame believes that this fate can be avoided by joining the Flame in death, and some cultists of the Keeper believe that proper devotion to him and/or the Dark Six can result in one’s soul being “kept” in some other (better?) afterlife.

The beliefs of the devotees to the Flame or Keeper fit within the Great Wheel pretty well, and the lack of Faerûn’s particular idiosyncracies (Wall of the Faithless etc.) is no big deal because that is known to be something specific to the Realms set up by Ao, the Realms’ overgod. No overgod is known for Eberron, but presumably it would have one if it is just another Material Plane within the Great Wheel—so it is possible that the unnamed overgod of Eberron has decreed that souls (usually) go to Dolurrh—wherever that is—on death, instead of their usual resting place with the appropriate plane or divine realm. Dolurrh itself might be just a demiplane, for example, since it doesn’t have anything in it and there’s no particular reason it would need to be large.

#### About gods in general

Talking about gods brings us to another issue: the gods themselves. Gods in Eberron work very differently from everywhere else, being so distant and aloof that you can’t *actually be sure they exist at all*.

This is pretty easily explained, though: just as Ao requires the gods of the Realms to deal special hoops to jump through ([necessitating the Wall of the Faithless](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62456/4563)), the unnamed overgod of Eberron requires gods there to be extremely hands-off, or limits how powerful the gods there are allowed to be, or bans them entirely.

Regardless, those gods, if they exist, are only those willing to put up with the requirements—which isn’t the major powers of the Great Wheel. Important deities in Eberron wouldn’t be worth even noticing elsewhere; they’re just the only ones willing to deal with the rules. Or quite simply none are (or the rules are simply “no gods”), and the faiths of Eberron are entirely in their believers’ imaginations.

Comment: I particularly like the section addressing: *Faerûn could reasonably produce warforged too*  As ever, another fine KR_Productions  offering. +1

Comment: As a bit of support for your "Faerun's lousy with mages, *somebody's* probably done it," there're new constructs in *Dragon Heist* that back your assertion up.

Comment: Minor note for the present time, it seems there may be more concrete info about Eberron and the Great Wheel included in the upcoming book 'Rising from the Last War', so it may be prudent to update this answer when that is available.

Answer (score 26):

4e's Dragon #371 ("*Origin Stories: Incorporating Races*", pages 40-42) discussed the idea of Warforged in Faerûn, mentioning the following five possibilities:

1. a one-off wizard experiment
2. a product of a (non-Thayan) Red Wizard Enclave
3. coming from Eberron by way of Sigil
4. travelling from the Returned Abeir nation of Gontal (possibly from a primordial's ancient shattered metallic fortress) or
5. awakening after a century of slumber near Lantan

That last one is my favorite:

Prior to Lantan sinking during Faerûn's Spellplague, it was a technologically advanced island (much like the legendary Atlantis) that developed highly advanced clockwork mechanisms and worshipped Gond. Indeed, techsmiths of Gond could construct a mechanical **Gondsman** as a loyal mechanical warrior, assistant, bodyguard, and friend (confusingly, priests of Gond were sometimes called Gondsmen as well).

Also note: the new Chult map in Tomb of Annihilation shows nearby Lantan as apparently resurfaced, so it might be an excellent time for a Gondsman (or similar construct) to appear.

Comment: Lantan is also mentioned in the "Artificers in Other Worlds" sidebar in the artificer class description: "In the Forgotten Realms, for example, the island of Lantan is home to many artificers, [...]"

Comment: What is a "non-Thayan" Red Wizard Enclave?  Isn't "Red Wizards" an organization based in Thay?

Comment: A large amount of Red Wizards were exiled from Thay after their civil war (and Szass Tam's takeover). They transformed enormously, becoming a loosely organized chain of merchant enclaves who specialized in procuring magical items.

Comment: "_awakening after a century of slumber near Lantan_" Mega Man X?

Answer (score 9):

### Travel to Eberron is possible, but poorly documented.

There is little to no evidence in Eberron lore that anyone has travelled there from another campaign setting. Nevertheless, it may be possible.

#### Visiting Eberron

According to the Player's Handbook, p.5:

> The worlds of the Dungeons & Dragons game exist within a vast cosmos called the **multiverse**, connected in strange and mysterious ways to one another and to other planes of existence [...] The legends of the Forgotten Realms, Dragonlance, Greyhawk, Dark Sun, Mystara, and Eberron settings are woven together in the fabric of the multiverse.

The DM is free to define just how, but traditionally, travel between campaign settings uses one of the following methods:

- **Planar travel**: One may travel betwen worlds using vast and mysterious other planes, such as the Astral Plane, Plane of Shadow (Shadowfell) or the Ethereal Plane. One might step into a doorway in the planar city of Sigil and find oneself in Khorvaire.
- **Spelljamming**: Ships are known to travel through the ether between the solar systems of worlds including those of the Forgotten Realms, Dragonlance and Greyhawk. The Spelljammer campaign setting pre-dates the release of Eberron, so there is no mention of Eberron in Spelljammer, but it remains possible.
- **Portals**: The Forgotten Realms has many portals to other worlds, including our Earth. It is not inconceivable that one would lead to Eberron.

#### Warforged built in Faerûn

Warforged may be built in the Forgotten Realms, as a kind of covergent evolution in design. The Realms has had many exceptionally talented mages, and it's very easy to imagine that one of them invented the Warforged, a kind of intelligent construct. Some possibilities:

- Warforged were built by an ancient fallen civilization. The secrets are lost, but some warforged have recently been built from parts kits found in the ruins of their dungeons. Were they creating an army? Host bodies to be possessed by mages seeking eternal life? We may never know.
- The warforged are an ancient race whose progenitors are unknown. They are all programmed with the secret knowledge of how to build new creatures of their type. They are rare and have avoided society for some time, to avoid being forced to create new members of their kind for evil uses.
- A Cannith forge was shifted to Toril during the Sundering, or captured and taken there by some deity.
- When Abeir and Toril were merged, it turned out that the warforged had existed on Abeir for thousands of years, where they were built as foot soldiers by a decadent civilization who did not wish to dirty their hands with the base matter of war. When the worlds split again, many warforged were left over on Toril.
- Warforged have simply existed in Faerûn for some time now, as a natural evolution of the traditional art of building iron golems.

#### Mystery

- You have no memory of your origins, and your reason for adventuring is to find answers. Who created you? Are there more of your kind?

Answer (score 8):

### For an easy connection: two-legged journey (layover in Sigil)

Based on a recent discussion with a 5e dev that addresses how 5e is accounting for previous lore and the settings that have not yet (in this edition) gotten full treatment, your Warforged can "get there from here."  Have a listen [to this discussion with one of the devs](https://www.youtube.com/embed/9JHyJj8C21c?wmode=opaque).

A key to solving the problem was pointed out [in this summary of the above link](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?652091-Sage-Advice-Plane-and-world-hopping-(includes-how-Eberron-and-Ravnica-fit-in-D-amp-D-cosmology)&p=7468234#post7468234):

1. Eberron's Crystal Sphere is cracking, possibly eventually allowing,
   say, a Spelljammer visit

and

2. **A portal, or portals, to Eberron exist in Sigil**.

*Caveat*: this is a dev talking, in the youtube. As far as I know this is not yet in official published material so you have to decide if you find it authoritative enough.  I do.  So does the DM in a campaign I am in where we have a Warforged (Monk) PC.

Sigil (originally from the Planescape setting) is mentioned in the 5e *Dungeon Masters Guide*, as is Eberron; their *existence* are both accepted in 5e official material.  The key piece is getting out of Eberron: the Crystal Sphere cosmology has made this a tough nut to crack in previous edition lore.

#### How does the Warforged get from Eberron-to-Sigil-to-Faerun?

1. The PC is doing something on Eberron, and is
   (a) fleeing from (something dangerous) and has to go through a gate
   (b) on a mission for powerful patron and is sent through the gate

and as a consequence ends up in Sigil.

2. Once in Sigil, the PC is helped by, or gets tricked by, *someone* - with the result being that they go through a gate that takes them to Faerun.

Gates are a thing in 5e, however you want to manage them.  You can use spells, or magical items, as the trigger for the PC going through a gate.

3. Your Warforged PC arrives in Faerun.  (As usual, the PC's luggage got sent to Denver. )

#### Even less complicated: use a *wish* spell

[The Weave is not limited to Toril/Faerun](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/98477/22566).  Given how broad *wish* is in terms of what it can do, and since the Weave is a common thread across all settings in the D&D 5e multiverse, you can cut out all of the above complications and have the travel from Eberron to Faerun be the result of a *wish*.  Make the details fit your setting and your world.

- Example scenario:
  The PC is a low rank warrior in a large fighting formation that is overrun by a numerically superior enemy.  The last few surviving members are on a mountain top.  The warforged PC picks up the fallen leader's sword (known to be magical) keeps on fighting this hopeless battle as more enemy forces come up the hill.  As the last of his comrades fall, and the sword sticks into the shield of his latest attacker, he mutters out loud:

  "I wish I were somewhere else; anywhere else!"

  The sword happens to be a *luck blade* with one last *wish* remaining on it.

The PC ends up in Faerun.  The sword doesn't.  The Warforged walks toward the nearest tavern ...

Comment: @KRyan The text box on page 205 of the PHB makes it clear that magic is magic across the whole multiverse, whatever one calls it.

Answer (score 7):

#### Travel from Eberron to Toril

You mention "lore that describe semi-permanent gateways between planes" and there is one that would fit almost perfectly to your goal: **The World Serpent Inn**. Here are the reasons why it would be a good fit:

- It is **accessible by low-level characters**. It is just an extraplanar inn with doors that open to pretty much everywhere in the multiverse and going in can be just as easy as entering the inn on one plane for a drink and exiting at another plane. Actually the first time it appeared in an official product was during AD&D 1e, *Tales of the Outer Planes*, a sourcebook with many miniadventures. In it the World Serpent Inn is introduced for 1st- and 2nd-level characters.
- The World Serpent Inn has an entrance in Arabel, Cormyr. This entrance has been there for a long-time, it was present in the above mentioned 1e adventure, it was later mentioned in the 2e sourcebooks *Forgotten Realms Adventures* (pages 74-75) and *In the Cage: A Guide to Sigil* (page 57), detailed in the *Volo's Guide to Cormyr* (pages 69-71, again 2e) and it was still there almost 20 years later in the [Dragon #351](https://archive.org/stream/DragonMagazine260_201801/DragonMagazine351#page/n13/mode/2up) (January 2007, 3.5e) article *World Serpent Inn*, written by long-time TSR and WotC veteran [Eric L. Boyd](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Eric_L._Boyd).

  > Although a portal to the **World Serpent Inn can appear anywhere in the Forgotten Realms**, just like in any other campaign setting, the only regular means ... requires a visit to the Wild Goose, a run-down tavern along the northern wall of the city of Arabel ...
- Even during the 3e that the cosmology of Eberron was considered entirely separate, it could be accessed through the World Serpent Inn. The same Dragon article mentions:

  > In **Eberron, the World Serpent Inn has a number of portals that open from time to time, all across the continent of Khorvaire and beyond**. Of these, only **one is relatively permanent**: the Queen's Kiss. Located in the bustling city of Fairhaven, the capitol of Aundair, the Queen's Kiss is a flower shop throughout the day, but those who approach it after hours often hear sounds of laughter and merriment, ...

In both cases the way the characters enter the Inn is by some little specific action, perhaps your player accidentally triggered the entrance. Or he happened to follow someone entering the Inn and afterwards got lost and ended up exiting on Faerun. Finally note that this means of travel can be made as **semi-permanent or temporary as you like, and could make an excellent character arc in the long-run**. After they get some levels, he might trace back his trail and you can bring him and the rest of his party to anywhere you like in the multiverse.

3.5e mechanics about the Inn are still available for free from the WotC website: http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/files/World_Serpent.pdf

---

#### Creation by a mad mage

The informative [answer by Matt Vincent](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131896/how-can-i-explain-a-race-from-5e-eberron-showing-up-in-faer%C3%BBn/131929#131929) mentions a "one-off wizard experiment" as a possibility suggested in Dragon #371. Since your target location for the character is Sword Coast, you might like to know that Undermountain, the many-levelled dungeon under Waterdeep, is the home of Trobriand the Metal Mage, who is an archmage (in)famous for building metallic constructs. We know from *Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage* (W:DotMM) that he is still alive in the body of an iron golem. While his constructs, such as his scorpion-like scaladars, generally have only animal-like intelligence (Int 1), there are at least two cases in the lore where they actually have gained free-will of their own:

1. *W:DotMM* describes two scaladars modified by illithids to house duergar brains. They have Int 11.
2. Even more relevant to your question, the 2e box set *The Ruins of Undermountain II: The Deep Levels*, introduces Squch, a self-aware scaladar created by Trobriand as one of his most intellectually stimulating experiments.

So it is not difficult to imagine that the "iron golem" Trobriand decides to create a humanoid servant this time and one of them gains independence and runs to the surface. You could also use this as an adventure hook for playing *W:DotMM* in the future. Perhaps there are others like the character? Some of those could be mindless copies. Or some self-aware ones are being used as slaves and the player might want to free them. You could even consider an evil twin story like Star Trek TNG's Lore-Data, with Trobriand playing the role of Dr. Soong.

<sub>PS: Since this question was asked a year ago, it is quite possible that the game is already ongoing at the moment. If that is the case and you have chosen Eberron or Lantan in the character's background, you might still consider introducing Trobriand as a villain interested in dismantling the character to understand how he works. He might get abducted and the party could try to save him from Undermountain.</sub>

Comment: It’s probably worth noting that *Dragon* magazine was published by Paizo under license from Wizards of the Coast at that time, which can make the canonicity of statements in *Dragon* article difficult. I, for one, have a very, very hard time rectifying a permanent, easily-accessible link between Eberron and the rest of the multiverse with the various things we know about Eberron and its culture. Nonetheless, +1, since it is (supposed to be, anyway) official and would certainly work for this character.

Comment: @KRyan: Thanks for the warning. I added that the author of the Dragon article was Eric L. Boyd, one of the veterans of the game. Yet, I must mention that I agree with your discomfort.

Answer (score 4):

> I am looking for a way to explain how the level 0/1 got to Faerûn. He does not need to be the source of the effect.

Possibly the best explanation is **no explanation** (yet).

The Warforged PC may remember little to nothing if the player isn't familiar with Eberron lore. Or the PC may remember their life in Eberron with perfect clarity, up to walking into a cave or tower or whatever as a beginning adventurer, then... waking up in a strange land.

Later on, as the campaign develops, and it becomes possible for the PCs to travel the planes (as this Warforged probably wants to, if they remember anything about coming from Eberron...), you may decide to make it an element of the campaign. Other answers offer good info on that. Also, how many creatures (NPCs or just monsters) from Eberron have ended up on Faerun, there's room for many plot hooks even if the nature of connection remains a mystery.

TL;DR At the start of the campaign you might not know what fits the campaign. You will make a better story if you discover the connection together with the players. Or it might never come up, remaining an eternal mystery. *This is ok.*

Answer (score 3):

### Just because the race is described for Eberron doesn't mean it can't exist in a different form in Faerûn

Of course this ultimately depends on what *exactly* your player(s) want to say or do, but if they just want to play a Warforged without insisting that they're originally from Eberron there are lots of alternative ways to go about it:

- They might be a rare remnant of a lost civilisation, only recently
  activated.
- They might be a recent innovation created by a Wizard, not yet ready
  for mass production.
- Their core could have been formed by a freak magical accident, with
  the rest of its body constructing itself around it.

There are plenty of ways you can go about justifying why a Warforged-like player race exists in a Faerûn-based campaign without having to try to literally transport a Warforged over from an entirely different setting. You could even decide that in your version of Faerûn, Warforged are a known, if rare, native race.

Always keep in mind that unless you're running something like an AL game, you are not strictly constricted to the exact descriptions of lore found in the core books and their various supplements even if you base your campaign off of them.

Answer (score 1):

When my group started playing Mines of Phandelver, I wanted to be a Warforged. My DM basically just migrated the basic lore of the Canniths and Warforged in. There are plenty of places that aren't really explored in campaign books, so just shove a forge somewhere that's not super explored.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community What would you like cited? The answer is talking about Ml Mn's first hand experience solving the issue.

Comment: @Non-novelist Community is an automatic bot; it’s not always correct. I think that comment happens when someone flags an answer—but whoever flagged this one was wrong. You are correct, this is a fine, complete, and appropriate answer. I’ve upvoted it, personally. Welcome to the site, Ml Mn.

Comment: @KRyan Correct, it's rhetorical for those flagging and upvoting the mistaken bot ;)

Answer (score 1):

#### *Dream of the Blue Veil*

The spell *dream of the blue veil* allows travel to other worlds:

> You and up to eight willing creatures within range fall unconscious for the spell’s duration and experience visions of another world on the Material Plane, such as Oerth, Toril, Krynn, or Eberron. If the spell reaches its full duration, the visions conclude with each of you encountering and pulling back a mysterious blue curtain. The spell then ends with you mentally and physically transported to the world that was in the visions.
>
> To cast this spell, you must have a magic item that originated on the world you wish to reach, and you must be aware of the world’s existence, even if you don’t know the world’s name.

While this doesn’t explain what a magic item from Faerun was doing in Eberron, it provides a method of travel from Eberron to Toril.

Answer (score 0):

## Your character might be a Planeswalker.

Since the settings of Magic: the Gathering are now (semi-)officially DND settings, that opens up the possibility of using a bit of MtG lore for PCs who have found themselves on a foreign world: they could simply be a planeswalker, a one-in-a-million Mage who has awakened their “planeswalker spark” and gained the ability to travel between different fantasy worlds. The rules for playing such a character in DND 5e are written in the appendix of the [free PDF supplement](https://media.wizards.com/2017/downloads/magic/plane-shift_amonkhet.pdf) Plane Shift: Amonkhet.

Comment: If I understand the document correctly, it would perhaps be better not to say Mage as the character does not need to be a wizard or any sort of spellcaster. Still +1 for the nice connection.

Comment: @ZwiQ In this particular case, I’m pretty sure that any class with some form of magical abilities would count, even if they’re not a spellcaster as such mechanically (e.g. Monks, Beast Totem Barbarians, and maybe even certain Fighter or Rogue subclasses). I don’t have any quotes to back that up, though.

Answer (score -1):

Eberron and the forgotten realms are not separate planes, they are actually separate crystal spheres. Crystal spheres are basically just different solar systems that dont necessarily have the same planes or exact physics.

The concept of traveling between these crystal spheres is called spelljamming. It's sort of like space but also like the multiverse it's very strange but it's how dnd handles campaign setting jumping.

If you want to put a war forged in the forgotten realms it would probably be easier to just have an npc invent them somewhere in your world, otherwise you'd have to wait until the party is kind of high level or at least accompanied by a high level arcane spellcaster, and then reinvent the spelljammer because they haven't been used in thousands of years in lore.

Comment: What lore says spelljammers haven’t been used in thousands of years? Spelljammers were definitely in use in the AD&D 2e era of Faerûn, and that’s only a couple centuries before the D&D 5e era of FR. As far as I know, WotC has never said anything positive or negative about the continued existence of spelljammers—they just have not published anything about them since the TSR buyout.

Comment: Suggestion: quoting a source book might make this answer more complete

Comment: wait, not weight. (voice to text can be a bother ....)

Answer (score -1):

In my campaign, which has not started yet, we'll play Curse of Strahd and one of the players asked me to be a Kalashtar. Naively, I agreed, without going after where that race is from. Now that I read it's from Eberron, here's how I picture that plane transition. Essentially nobody will care since we don't have players that are deep into lore, but here's my suggestion to that player:

A female Kalashtar (a Human possessed by a Quori) is pregnant with this player. When she is about to give birth, this Quori possesses the baby. Suddenly, the mom is not in pain anymore. The two midwives that are helping in the delivery glance at each other when the baby simply vanishes.
In a camp near Daggerford, a group of merchants hear a baby crying. When they finally track where the crying is coming from, they spot a newborn on the grass and one of the merchants hears a voice in her head: "I'm hungry".

In this case, the act of giving birth exuded such a great amount of power that allowed that Quori to travel through planes, and since he had the baby with it, the baby went along for the ride. That didn't happen by choice, it was more like a magical push/explosion. I know that this might have its flaws and it's not 100% what OP is looking for, since you can't give birth to a machine, but it's one explanation that I could come up with regarding plane switching.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Unfortunately, this site may be a little different from what you’re used to on discussion forums and the like—we really stick pretty strictly to the whole “Q&A” thing. That means that answers have to stick pretty closely to the question, so this one may not be very well-received. Certainly an interesting story you have there, it’s just not necessarily an answer to this question. For what it’s worth, depending on how you’re running *Curse of Strahd*, the more straight-forward solution would be to use the Mists—which are known to wisk people away from their own planes.

Comment: I discuss more about how the Mists bring people to Ravenloft [in this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/167894/4563). Note that some of this may be specific to the Demiplane of Dread incarnation of Ravenloft, in which Strahd’s Barovia is just one of many Domains within Ravenloft.

Comment: @KRyan well, the title question is: "How can I explain a race from Eberron showing up in Faerûn?"

Strictly speaking, the Kalashtar are a race from Eberron and I explained how I'll get them to Faerûn, so I'm not 100% off here.

And, by the way, that's how I came across this particular link, so I thought I'd share my thoughts on how I'll do that, so other DMs can use that or a similar approach in their games. If that's a reason to get -1, than I'm guilty of all charges. Sorry.

Comment: For the record, I did not downvote—that must have been someone else. But this answer does feel very specific to the kalashtar, and the title is not the entirety of the question. If you want to suggest an edit to the question to mention “warforged” rather than “a race from Eberron,” that would be acceptable, but either way, the question *is* about warforged. I suspect whoever did vote is responding to that, and I fear others are likely to do so in the future. What you choose to do with that information is, of course, entirely up to you.

Answer (score -3):

#### Don’t.

Seriously: backstories usually affect the game about as much as PC’s hair color. So don’t spend brainpower on it any more than you would if a player wanted purple hair. Unless your player has indicated that they are interested in a backstory-driven campaign, it simply *doesn’t matter.*

That said, you should figure out how much social roleplay you want to do this campaign. If it’s going to be significant, figure out what reactions to the warforged will be like and let the player know ahead of time. Alternately, if you’re just running a dungeon crawl, let your player write whatever he wants.