# Is it possible for a cleric in the Forgotten Realms to get his power from Thor?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

I am looking for an answer referring to the logistics lore-wise and in terms of mechanics in general.

Comment: Could you clarify whather you are the player or the GM in this instance ? This could help us give better answers

Comment: If they op is looking for lore why does is matter if they are GM or player? Lore is lore. Yes a GM can make a change, but that wouldn't be forgotten realms lore.

Comment: @SeriousBri "and in terms of mechanics in general"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide (page 20):

> The Faerunian pantheon isn't the only one known on Toril. ... people in faraway lands are known to worship altogether different gods. Occasionally, foreigners bring the worship of these gods to Faerun. In addition, on rare occasions a new god comes into being, ... In cosmopolitan places such as Waterdeep and Calimshan, small shrines and temples to strange gods spring up from time to time.

> Over generations, a new god might become a settled-in member of the pantheon. Indeed, some scholars posit that Faerun has many "immigrant" gods, who joined the pantheon's ranks so long ago that their foreign origins are lost in antiquity.

Some examples of immigrant deities include Tyr, Mielikki, Oghma and Loviatar. Such "interloper" or "multi-spheric" deities have been a part of the Forgotten Realms setting from its very inception by Ed Greenwood (see Dragon magazine issue 54 from October 1981). So it would not be unusual to put in a cleric of Thor if your DM does not object to it.

(It is worth noting that in the older editions of the game, if you were a priest in a crystal sphere where your deity did not have an established base, you would not be able to receive spells above the 2nd level. You would have to use a special spell called *[Contact Home Power](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84098/what-happens-to-a-priest-travelling-from-one-world-to-another-in-the-prime-mater)* to (partially) overcome this limitation. However there is no such written constraint in 5e.)

Comment: There's even canonical history of deities worshipped on Earth being imported into the Forgotten Realms - the Mulhorandi are the descendants of ancient Egyptians who were captured and brought to Toril, and the [Mulhorandi Pantheon](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Mulhorandi_pantheon) are incarnations of the gods of ancient Egypt who followed them to the Realms. There's no such canonical history given for the Norse gods, but the Mulhorandi example is at least precedent that this kind of thing can happen.

Comment: @Carcer Tyr is also a Norse god from Earth who's worshipped in the Realms, so there's definitely precedent.

Comment: @Draconis I completely forgot Tyr was originally Norse! In fact, his [FR wiki article](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Tyr) notes: "if a cleric of the Norse pantheon came to Toril from another world, [they] would be granted spells through Tyr", at least according to 2e Spelljammer - so, if strictly adhering to the established lore, a Thor-worshipping cleric in the Realms would likely be empowered by Tyr in Thor's stead, Thor not being available to do it himself.